# Power function Sql only 3dp

Tags: sql, decimal

```
select power(1.005,4) [Power]
```

gives 1.020

```
select 1.005*1.005*1.005*1.005 [Manual]
```

gives 1.020150500625

i need the latter result but don't want to do manually.  4th Power in this case but will be variable.

please advise. thanks

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your syntax, I assume you are using SQL Server.  As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql) for `power()`:

> Returns the same type as submitted in float_expression. For example,
>   if a decimal(2,0) is submitted as float_expression, the result
>   returned is decimal(2,0).

SQL Server interpets numeric inputs as decimals, not floats.  So, if you want the full value, convert the value *before* calling the function:

```
select power(convert(float, 1.005), 4) as [Power]
```

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/MOHDP24248) comparing the different approaches.